# Is there any way to click same icon?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to click that all rectangle icon (icon look like football stadium) under Goal Line In-Play from page. I tried many times but it does not work. Please help me if there anyone know how to click those all icons.

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
# chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe")
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {"source": 
"""Object.defineProperty(navigator, 
'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})"""})

url = 'https://www.bet365.com/#/IP/B1'
driver.get(url)
sleep(10)
res = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
sleep(10)

click_icon = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".ovm-MediaIconContainer_Buttons div")
click_icon.click()
```

Comment: Try `click_icon = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".ovm-MediaIconContainer_Buttons")`

Comment: it only click the first icon, It does not click the remaining icons

Comment: Use `find_elements_by_css_selector(...)` to return a list. For each element, call `click()`

Comment: I tried as you said and it gives me error, click_icon = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".ovm-MediaIconContainer_Buttons")
click_icon.click() File "C:/Users/NYI/PycharmProjects/THProject/main.py", line 19, in <module>
    click_icon.click()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(moving comment to answer)

Two issues:

- You're searching for class and tag using `find_element_by_css_selector`. Change this to only search on class name.
- To return an element collection, use `find_elements_by_css_selector` which returns an element list.

Replace this code:

```
click_icon = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".ovm-MediaIconContainer_Buttons div")
click_icon.click()
```

With this:

```
icon_list = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".ovm-MediaIconContainer_Buttons")
for icon in icon_list:  # every icon in list
    icon.click()  # click single icon
```

Comment: I replaced it as you said
icon_list = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".ovm-MediaIconContainer_Buttons")
for icon in click_list:  # every icon found
    icon.click()  # click single icon
then i got this error.
File "C:/Users/NYI/PycharmProjects/THProject/main.py", line 19, in <module>
    for icon in click_list:  # every icon found
NameError: name 'click_list' is not defined

Could you please show me full codes that is working?

Comment: Thank you so much, You are amazing. It works now. Sorry for that I don't have programming knowledges. Could i ask more questions you? I don't know how to use this website but this website is useful.